# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: How did Community ask this?

Comment: @DoubleAA Community is Magic sometimes. :D

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9445/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, yeah, that seems to be a significant issue in this election so far. I hope people will get over it now that [I've broken the ice](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-17624). There are a few people around here who should be able to make a clear case for themselves as mods (including saying a great deal more that I have so far) without boasting improperly.

Comment: @Issac Moses, may I ask why withdraw your nomination?

Comment: That didn't ping him, @Kaveh.

Comment: @msh210 Shouldn't this be re-tagged status-completed?

Comment: @SethJ, I don't know. There's no official result yet.

Comment: @msh210, the results are downloadable. I can't access them at work, but they exist. I don't don't know if anything is going to be posted otherwise, do you?

Comment: @SethJ, I'm pretty sure that SE staff will post the official results here.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, alright. I was going to post a separate question asking that. Thanks.

Comment: ...and so they did http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1311/759